# Bibliography with names separated by a comma, not by "and"?

Tags: bibliographies

My text is in German yet I'm using the style `alpha` and not `alphadin` because I don't like the capitalization and the word order in the latter. The only problem I have with `alpha` is that it separates the names by "and":

> [AZ10] Martin Aigner and Günter M. Ziegler. *Das Buch der Beweise.* Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2010.

And I'd like it to be separated by a comma.

My code, in case it might be relevant:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@BOOK{Aigner2010,
    AUTHOR = {Martin Aigner and G{\"u}nter M. Ziegler},
    YEAR = {2010},
    TITLE = {Das Buch der Beweise},
    ISBN = {978-3-642-02259-3},
    PUBLISHER = {Springer},
    ADDRESS = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to stick with BibTeX, it turns out not to be too difficult to create a modified form of the file `alpha.bst` that achieves your objective.

- Find the file `alpha.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call it, say, `alphacomma.bst`.  (Don't edit a file from the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `alphacomma.bst` in a text editor.
- Find the two instances of the string `" and "`. One instance is (most likely) on line 203 in the function `format.names`, the other on line 482 in the function `format.crossref.editor`.
- Replace both instances of `" and "` with `", "`. Notice the space after the comma.
- In the function `format.names`, on line 198 (or so), locate the line

  ```
                  { "," * }
  ```

  (This line immediately follows the line that contains the code `{ numnames #2 >`.)

  Change this line to

  ```
                  { "" * }
  ```

  In case you're curious: In the original version of `alpha.bst`, if an entry has three or more authors, a comma is inserted before the final author. Since we're now using `,` as the generic delimiter between *all* authors, it's no longer necessary to insert a comma before the final author.
- Save the file `alphacomma.bst` either in the directory/folder where your main `.tex` file is located or in a directory/folder that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution appropriately.
- Start using the new bibliography file by using the instruction `\bibliographystyle{alphacomma}`. Run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%%\usepackage[alpha]{natbib}  % 'natbib' not really useful with alpha style

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Aigner2010,
    AUTHOR = {Martin Aigner and G{\"u}nter M. Ziegler},
    YEAR = {2010},
    TITLE = {Das Buch der Beweise},
    ISBN = {978-3-642-02259-3},
    PUBLISHER = {Springer},
    ADDRESS = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{Aigner2010}
\bibliographystyle{alphacomma}
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is  a solution using `biblatex`. (If you don't want the ISBN to be printed, load `biblatex` with the option `isbn=false`.)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Aigner2010,
  author = {Martin Aigner and G{\"u}nter M. Ziegler},
  year = {2010},
  title = {Das Buch der Beweise},
  isbn = {978-3-642-02259-3},
  publisher = {Springer},
  address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
%natbib=true, % not needed here but FYI
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: FWIW, the `biblatex` option `style=alphabetic` seems to typeset the contents of the `publisher` and `address` fields in the opposite ordering of that produced by the BibTeX style `alpha`.